# Can people know you read their tweets even if you don't favorite or retweet them?

Tags: twitter

So I know you can tell someone is stalking you if they accidently favorite your tweet even though they don't follow you, but are there other ways you can tell?

Like with an IP address? Or something else?

Comment: Twitter is public anyway, I don't think we should ever talk about *stalking* on it. Also this doesn't mean that he was on your profile, it could simply mean that person follows some users who follow you and got one of your tweets in his "Discover" tab and accidentally clicked favorite.

Answer (score 3):

No.

And (unless you have some other evidence) I'd hardly call it "stalking" just because a non-follower favours your Tweets.